# Determine if a Processor is AMD64 or Intel64?

Tags: visual-c++, wix, inno-setup

The Visual Studio C++ compiler [provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173505.aspx) the command line compiler options `/favor:AMD64` and `/favor:INTEL64` to optimize for AMD64 or Intel64 processors respectively. Now, the terms AMD64 and Intel64 [are essentially interchangeable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) for most purposes, but there [are some differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64) that the compiler can optimise for.

On Microsoft Windows 7, is there a reliable way to check at application install time whether we're installing on an AMD64 or INTEL64 system?

I'm using InnoSetup and WiX for installers, and I'm speculating about selecting the version to install based on AMD64 or INTEL64 CPU.

---

*Edit: Some notes in retrospect*

In the end, the answers from [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493311/385094) and [Andrew Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492582/385094) both gave good solid strategies for approaching this issue, but as neither of them are really firmly future proof, personally I'm going to stick with the default `/favor:blend` for my project.

Comment: The raw assembler x86 `CPUID` instruction will tell you exactly what processor you're on. I'd be very surprised if there aren't higher-level functions which give you cpuid's data in a nicer format.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888731

Comment: @HansPassant, that link gave some handy info, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Win32_Processor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMi class, from Inno setup you can execute a WMI query without problems. Check this sample:

```
var
  FSWbemLocator : Variant;
  FWMIService   : Variant;
  FWbemObject   : Variant;
begin
FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WBEMScripting.SWBEMLocator');
FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
FWbemObject   := FWMIService.Get('Win32_Processor');
if FWbemObject.Architecture=9 then //is a 64 bits processor
  if  FWbemObject.Family=131 then  //all 64-bit AMD processors are identified by using a Family attribute value of 0x83 (131).
```

From here you can use the Architecture, Family, Manufacturer and other properties to determine the processor type.

Comment: Shiny. This does seem more robust than parsing the environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `%PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER%` environment variable.

On AMD systems the value ends with "AuthenticAMD".

On Intel systems the value ends with "GenuineIntel".

(at least for the samll number of systems I've checked)

Comment: That seems close. Further, it seems AMD systems always contain "AMD64" and Intel systems contain either "EM64T" or "Intel64".

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use a combination if the [`Msix64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [`Intel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows installer properties to determine it? This is obviously assuming that the `Intel` property is set correctly for AMD64 processors. There is the [`Intel64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property too but that only shows if the processor is an Itanium one which I assume you are not bothered about.